# Using *ngFor to populate a radio list formatted across 3 divs

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Creating a dynamic radio button list across a row with 3 divs. I am trying to make a three column layout of the radio buttons from a list on the component. I will repeat over the MajorExposureItems array and grab each name as an option to a radio button group. The problem I am having is how to nest the repeat to split the array into three lists that I can then put into the 3 columns.

I have tried this blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cudyel

```
onItemChange(item) {
  console.log("onItemChange(): ", item)
}

MajorExposureItems = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Camp',
  value: 'CAMP'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Child Day Care',
  value: 'CHILDDAYCARE'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Event Space',
  value: 'EVENTSPACE'
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'Festival / Fair',
  value: 'FESTIVAL'
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: 'Hospital',
  value: 'HOSPITAL'
}, {
  id: 6,
  name: 'Hotel / Motel',
  value: 'HOTEL'
}, {
  id: 7,
  name: 'Long-term care / Nursing home',
  value: 'LONGTERMCARE'
}, {
  id: 8,
  name: 'Office / Indoor workplace',
  value: 'OFFICE'
}, {
  id: 9,
  name: 'Other healthcare facility',
  value: 'OTHERHEALTHCARE'
}, {
  id: 10,
  name: 'Prison / Jail',
  value: 'PRISON'
}, {
  id: 11,
  name: 'Private Home / Residence',
  value: 'RESIDENCE'
}, {
  id: 12,
  name: 'Religious Facility',
  value: 'RELIGIOUS'
}, {
  id: 13,
  name: 'Restaurant',
  value: 'RESTAURANT'
}, {
  id: 14,
  name: 'School / College / University',
  value: 'SCHOOL'
}, {
  id: 15,
  name: 'Shelter / Group Home',
  value: 'SHELTER'
}, {
  id: 16,
  name: 'Ship / Boat',
  value: 'BOAT'
}, {
  id: 17,
  name: 'Unknown',
  value: 'UNKNOWN'
}, {
  id: 18,
  name: 'OTHER DESCRIPTION',
  value: 'OTHERDESCRIPTION'
}]
```

And in my html:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div class="columns">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="column" *ngFor="let item of MajorExposureItems; let i = index">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="MajorExposureModel" #majorExposureModel="ngModel" id="MajorExposure{{item.id}}" value="{{item.value}}" (change)="onItemChange(item)" /> {{item.name}}
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I can only figure how to format this layout in one column. I would like to evenly distribute this to a 3 column layout. Any suggestions?

Comment: where are your bootsrap styles? may be that's why you don't see it properly

Comment: Have you tried using any css styles to achieve the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a few things...

- First, i added the bootstrap css file to index.html
- next to distribute the '*dynamic*' radio buttons into 3 divs, we can take advantage of `column-count` property of CSS;
- while to distribute the '*fixed*' options a,b,c... we can use bootstrap class of `col-md-4`;

relevant **HTML**:

```
<div  >
    <div class="myColumns" >
        <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let item of MajorExposureItems; let i = index">
            <input  
                class="form-check-input" 
                type="radio" 
                [(ngModel)]="MajorExposureModel" 
                #majorExposureModel="ngModel"
                id="MajorExposure{{item.id}}"
                value="{{item.value}}" 
                (change)="onItemChange(item)"/>

                {{item.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
<hr/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-md-4">a </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-md-4">b</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-md-4">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

relevant **CSS**:

```
.myColumns{-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
  column-count: 3;}
```

complete [working demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f4g4br)